# Is it possible to restrict modeline in vim to only allow certain settings?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Is there a way to configure vim to enable 'modeline' (and by extension, setting 'modelines' to be non-zero), but restricting the parsing capability of modelines in files?

I want to enable setting of tabstops, softtabstops, and filetype in files, while keeping modelines otherwise disabled (for security cosiderations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the vim plugin [securemodelines : Secure, user-configurable modeline support](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1876)  to whitelist allowed commands in modelines. Note that the version on vim.org is 5 years old, the latest version of the plugin on github has some minor tweaks.

Comment: Thanks. This has exactly the features I was looking for. I had to learn about using vim plugins, which led me to the amazing [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), which was followed by the even more amazing [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)).